# Editing an entity that has a file - Default Model Binder Confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model like this

```
public class FileDetail 
{
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }

    public void UploadFile()
    {
        if (File != null)
        {

        try
        {
                ...
                Url = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(objImageBytes);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I have Edit/Create view like this

```
...

@model ApplicationBase.Core.Common.FileDetail

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.File, new { type = "file", accept = "*" })

...
```

**When I do Edit action , default modal binder loads file property as string,**

```
Request.Form
{File=17382.jpg}
```

**When I do Create action, default modal binder loads file as HttpFileCollectionWrapper**

```
Request.Form
{}

Request.Files
{System.Web.HttpFileCollectionWrapper}
    AllKeys: {string[1]}
    Count: 1
```

Why this is happening ? This should be always be as HttpFileCollectionBase but when I create a new entity it runs perfect, then when I edit same entity it binds File property as string not file ?

Whats the problem here ?

**EDITED**

I do not save File property to db. I only use it to bind file type from input field then I run UploadFile method. That method gets file and create a base64 string and put it to Url property of FileDetail.

Then I save entity to db.

**EDITED 2**

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Create")]
    public ActionResult CreateConfirmed(FileDetail Detail)
    {
    ...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(FileDetail Detail)
    {

    }
```

Comment: When you edit the form, do you browse for a new file?

Comment: Yes I browse for a new file. But this time, it is not binded as file. Its binded as string as the filename

Comment: Can you post your Create and Edit Actions. Also, why do you have the UploadFile method in your Model? That should be in your Controller.

Comment: Actually FileDetail is not an simple entity. It is a business object so it does some business related with itself. I am simplyfing problem here. Normally Action methods parameters are different. But it doesnt matter for this scenario because I just watch Request.Files in them.

Comment: So, when you watch Request.Files in Edit Action, you can see the file?

Comment: I see it in the Create Action but not in the Edit Action.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34565/discussion-between-ataravati-and-ryu-kaplan)

Comment: Do you use a single view for both actions? If not, do they both have multipart forms?

Comment: Thats the answer. I forgot to add multipart attr to Edit one

Comment: Write it as an answer pls to accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your Views have multipart forms like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(action, controller, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data"})
{
}
```